# Connecting Linksys Wi-Fi USB adapter

Tags: wireless

I've just installed a Ubuntu 13.10 CD on a desktop and I was planning to connect to the internet with a USB adapter when I realize that I can't connect my Linksys Wi-Fi USB adapter adapter to Linux. It does not appear in the network manager.

Answer (score 1):

From the USB identifier (in this case, 13B1:0029, also known as VID_13B1&PID_0029), you can research driver information.

[wikidevi.com](https://wikidevi.com/) is a superb resource to research, and that USB device is https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Linksys_WUSB300N.

Unfortunately, this device has no Linux driver support. While you could try to [Ndiswrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper), you will find that this very old device only has 32-bit NDIS drivers and will not work with 64-bit Ubuntu editions.

You would be well advised to locate a USB Wi-Fi device with native support.